# Blank images when attempting to load image into tkinter window

Tags: python, image, tkinter, python-3.7, tk-toolkit

So what's happening is that I have a PNG file saved in my directory. I am trying to create a program that loads this picture onto a window 3 times. I am using tkinter for the UI and its PhotoImage class to do this. To load a picture I normally create a class and then load put a button in it with the 'image parameter'. However, when I try to run this program, it only loads the 3rd picture. The 1st and 2nd one just appear as blank boxes. Can somebody help me?
The code is below:

```
from tkinter import *

def add():
    imageClass = PhotoImage(file="updated.png")
    button = Button(root, compound=TOP, image=imageClass, pady=20, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    button.pack()

root = Tk()

root.config(bg="white")

for i in range(3):
    root.update()
    imageClass = PhotoImage(file="updated.png")
    button = Button(root, compound=TOP, image=imageClass, pady=20, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the 'add' function. I was using it for something else but i forgot to remove it

Comment: Why don't you just move the line `imageClass = PhotoImage(...)` before the for loop if all the buttons use the same picture?

Comment: Yes that has worked thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is your images are being stored on **every iteration of the `for` loop** as `imageClass = PhotoImage(file="updated.png")`

`imageClass` gets its value overriden for every `i`, and when the loop finally exits only **one** reference in `imageClass` remains, hence why the 3rd image appers and others do not.

Thus you need to store every PhotoImage "reference" somewhere, for example in a global dictionary

```py
root = Tk()

# Modification 1
myImageClasses = dict()

root.config(bg="white")

for i in range(3):
    root.update()
    # Modification 2
    myImageClasses[i] = PhotoImage(file="updated.png")
    button = Button(root, compound=TOP, image=myImageClasses[i], pady=20, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
    button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Oh, I totally understand now! Thanks so much everyone who helped me